# Unattended GnuPG Key Generation for ECC

Tags: bash, gnupg, batch

I'm trying to create an ECC PGP unattended within a bash script. It looks like this:

```
cat >ecc <<EOF
Key-Type: ECC
Key-Length: 521
Subkey-Type: ECC
Subkey-Length: 521
Name-Real: Test
Passphrase: secret
Expire-Date: 0
%pubring gpg.pub
%secring gpg.sec
%commit
EOF
gpg --batch --yes --no-tty --gen-key ecc
```

This is working for RSA keys quite well, but for the above example for ECC it says:

```
gpg: key generation failed: Unknown elliptic curve
```

How can I specify the elliptic curve to use?

Comment: What Ubuntu are you using?  Do you have `gpg` or `gpg2`?  If you are not on 16.04, you are not going to be able to generate an ECC curve key.  If you are using `gpg` and not `gpg2` you also won't be able to do anything with ECC curves.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and have aliased gpg to gpg2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a Fedora user, but hear me out Ubuntu fans. I was struggling with the same problem, so here's my solution that works for Fedora 25 with GnuPG 2.1.13, and surely under Ubuntu. It's a modification of Thomas' answer. Set the Key-Type and Subkey-Type as follows (I'm using nistp256 but use whatever curve your system supports):

> Key-Type: ECDSA
>   Key-Curve: nistp256
>   <s>Key-Length: 256</s>
>   Subkey-Type: ECDH
>   Subkey-Curve: nistp256
>   <s>Subkey-Length: 256</s>

If you use ECC as key-type and subkey-type, gpg will generate errors like this, and the public key will be ECDH, not ECDSA.

gpg: error reading rest of packet: Invalid argument
gpg: error reading rest of packet: Invalid argument
gpg: can't encode a 256 bit MD into a 72 bits frame, algo=8
gpg: can't encode a 256 bit MD into a 72 bits frame, algo=8

Also, note that in GnuPG v2.1 and later, the options **%pubring** and **%secring** are ignored (https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html) so don't use them.

And finally, check this out https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#ecc it's a good read about which curves to use. In fact, for me, v2.1.13 is only listing the following, during the manual command:

```
$ gpg2 --expert --full-gen-key
...
(3) NIST P-256
(4) NIST P-384
(5) NIST P-521
```

Comment: Nice answer. This is not only working on Ubuntu through Docker but also on my host ArchLinux machine where gpg doesn't even know what ECC as key type could be. Actually you dont even need to specify Key-Length

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the Key-Length, indeed it's not required in this case. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Complimenting @upteryx's excellent answer, here is a [complete GPG key gen script](https://gist.github.com/SomajitDey/1c458b7191935b36f04eec08e62bf9c1) using EDDSA (ed25519) for signing (primary key) and ECDH (curve 25519) for encryption (subkey). The main difference with @upteryx's scheme are:

> Key-Type: EDDSA

> Key-Curve: ed25519

> Subkey-Type: ECDH

> Subkey-Curve: cv25519